# Collision detection between a bullet and enemy

Tags: collision-detection

I've been trying to implement collision detection into a simple game I'm making. I've looked around and everything points me back to the equation I have done for my dist. However it doesn't quite work. Am I missing something? Or am I completely wrong?

```c
bool collisionquery(enemy z){ 
    double dist = sqrt((px - z.getpx()) * (px - z.getpx()) +
                       (py - z.getpy()) * (py - z.getpy()) +
                       (pz - z.getpz()) * (pz - z.getpz()));

    if (dist < 0.1*getbulletsize())
    {
        cout << "hit\n";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It looks OK; maybe increase the margin against which you compare `dist`? You're only taking the bullet size into consideration, not enemy size.

Comment: I'm assuming your bullet is moving? It might simply be moving so fast that in the discrete times where you check it's either in front of or behind the enemy, never registering the hit. And you don't give yourself much of a margin either with the bullet size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What scenarios does this code no work for? I'd imagine this algorithm would work (finding the distance between two objects is less than their radius) also there may be serious inaccuracies when encountering objects with large velocities.

An issue you may encounter is that you cannot accurately determine the time of collision as you are assuming collisions can only occur at the end of an animation frame rather than during the frame. An animation frame assumes the velocity is constant between 0 -> 1 where acceleration has already been used to compute V.

To keep things simple, I suggest approximating both bodies as sphere with radius R1 and R2.

If this is the case, you'll need to account for:

1 - The radius of the two bodies. In this case the enemy will be a point of radius 0 and the bullet will have radius getBulletSize();

2 - The velocity of the bullet and the enemy during the animation frame is between 0<=t<=1.

The case of the collision will occur when  |r1 + r2| < d, where d is the distance between both bodies centre of mass.

d is given as P(t) - Q(t), Q and P are the centre of mass of both objects. 
P(t) = P0 + Vp*t.
Q(t) = Q0 + Vq*t.

Vp = P1 - P0;
Vq = Q1 - Q0;

=> d = P(t) - Q(t)

Solving for the case (R1 + R2)^2 = (P(t) - Q(t))^2 will produce the time of collision. Don't be scared of this formulae! It solves to a simple second order polynomial of which the quadratic formula will solve for t. If B^2 > 0 in the formulae, first time of surface collision occurs when the time is a minimum!

Collision Cases:

Occurs if:

1) 0 <= t <= 1.

Preliminary Check:

2) minimum d (derivative of radius condition = 0) must be < R1 + R2

Hope this helps!!! Let me know if I have misunderstood you or am talking gibberish :)

Answer (score 0):

Was simply just too small of a comparison of dist, that I didn't notice.
Thanks.